# Java.Польза от ссылок(SoftReference,  WeakReference , PhantomReference)

Tags: java, jvm, сборщик-мусора

Используя различные ссылки можно получить большую скорость работы сборщика мусора или для иных целей используются ссылки?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Разница не в скорости, разница в том, как сборщик мусора будет работать с объектом по ссылке.

`SoftReference` — это самая сильная из всех перечисленных ссылок. Если на объект не осталось больше нормальных ссылок, а только `SoftReference`, объект не будет съеден сборщиком мусора до тех пор, пока реально не возникнет ситуация нехватки памяти.

Хороший пример использования для таких ссылок -- кеш больших картинок в памяти. Если память исчерпалась, картинку выбросит сборщик мусора, и вы сможете перечитать её с диска, когда она снова вам понадобится.

`WeakReference` слабее: она не увеличивает дополнительно время жизни объекта, на который ссылается, и если на объект есть не более чем слабые ссылки, сборщик мусора может убрать его когда ему вздумается.

Хороший пример использования для таких ссылок -- добавить дополнительную информацию об каком-то объекте. Для этого вы держите в своём контейнере не сам объект, а лишь `WeakReference` на него, вместе с необходимой информацией, тем самым вы не мешаете объекту умереть вовремя и не меняете свойства остальной части программы.

Имея на руках `SoftReference` или `WeakReference` на ещё живой объект, вы можете получить настоящую ("сильную") ссылку, и предотвратить съедение этого объекта сборщиком мусора. Имея сильную ссылку, вы можете работать с объектом как обычно.

`PhantomReference` ещё слабее. Она не только не предохраняет объект от уборки, она даже не даёт возможности получить сильную ссылку. Вы можете только узнать, что объект собирается умереть, и предпринять какие-то действия по очистке; предотвратить смерть объекта вы не сможете.

---

При создании `SoftReference`, `WeakReference` вы можете, а при создании `PhantomReference` должны указать `ReferenceQueue` (хотя тут можно указать `null`, это обычно бессмысленно). После того, как объект будет убран сборщиком мусора, ссылка попадает в указанную вами `ReferenceQueue`.

Для нефантомных ссылок при добавлении в очередь финализатор уже выполнен и память объекта уже освобождена, но для фантомных добавление происходит после вызова финализатора до очистки памяти. Вы можете по сути не объявлять дорогой финализатор, а воспользоваться фантомной ссылкой из очереди для того, чтобы самостоятельно освободить ассоциированные ресурсы. (Для этого вы не сможете использовать сам объект, т. к. сильную ссылку на него невозможно получить из фантомной ссылки; но вы можете унаследоваться от `PhantomReference`, чтобы добавить нужную информацию в объект-ссылку.)

Ещё одно отличие, как подсказывает @gstackoverflow в комментариях, состоит в том, что фантомную ссылку вы должны очистить вручную, иначе объект будет оставаться (фантомно) достижим. Только после этого объект будет окончательно удалён.

Источники:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3329691/276994
- https://habrahabr.ru/post/169883/
- http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/referenceclasses.html

Comment: (Вот ещё по теме: <http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references>)

Comment: Спасибо большое за перевод:)
Я читал, в целом смысл был примерно понятен, но столько деталей я не смог вытащить самостоятельно.

Comment: @alex91: Пожалуйста! Некоторые детали пришли из личного опыта :)

Comment: @VladD Насчёт фантомных ссылок неверно, насколько я понимаю.  **Вы можете только узнать, что объект собирается умереть, и предпринять какие-то действия по очистке;** мы получаем фантомную ссылку на объект в очередь ReferenceQueue. пока у нас имеется эта ссылка, память не очистится. Мы сами можем вызвать на этой ссылке .clear и тогда память освободится.

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Ну, это несколько выходило за рамки короткого ответа. Дополнил, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD может Вы мне подскажете. Зачем мы передаем referenceQueue для soft/weak ссылок. идея в том, что мы поллим эту очередь на предмет появления новых объектов. Это будет значить, что память, которую занимал объек, освобождена. А почему нельзя поллить эту weak/soft ссылку ? visibility?

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Думаю, это для единообразия. Ну и одна очередь может обслуживать все типы ссылок. Кроме того, не зря у `Soft`/`WeakReference` есть конструктор без `ReferenceQueue` :)

Answer (score 4):

Скоростью управлять не получиться. Но более эффективно использовать память - да.

PhantomReference Вам навряд ли придется использовать.

Почитайте о [них](http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/referenceclasses.html).